# @Environment(\.presentationMode) cause textfield wrapped UIViewRepresentable to get cleared?

Tags: swift, swiftui, uitextfield

Because of limited capabilities in SwiftUI textfield i have wrapped the textfield UIViewRepresentable. The issue is when i navigate from a view that has a @Environment(.presentationMode) variable(that i use to dismiss a given view) to a given view that has a UIViewRepresentable textfild the text fields get cleared as soon as i change the selection. how to fix this?

Code i use for the text field

```
struct CustomTextFieldUI: UIViewRepresentable {

    // 1
    @Binding var text: String
    @Binding var isFocused: Bool
    var placeHolderText = ""
    @Binding var didEndEditing:Bool
    
     // 2
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<CustomTextFieldUI>) -> UITextField {
        
        
        let tf = UITextField(frame: .zero)
        tf.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        tf.delegate = context.coordinator
        tf.textColor = UIColor.white
        tf.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
        tf.font = UIFont(name: "Rubik-Medium", size: 14)
        tf.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeHolderText, attributes: [
            .foregroundColor: UIColor(red: 0.20, green: 0.20, blue: 0.20, alpha: 1.00),
            .font: UIFont(name: "Rubik-Medium", size: 14)!
        ])
        return tf
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> CustomTextFieldUI.Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(text: $text, isFocused: $isFocused, endEditing: $didEndEditing)
    }

    // 3
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = text
       // uiView.isSecureTextEntry = !isRevealed
        
    }

    // 4
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
        @Binding var text: String
        @Binding var isFocused: Bool
        @Binding var endEditing: Bool

        init(text: Binding<String>, isFocused: Binding<Bool>, endEditing: Binding<Bool>) {
            _text = text
            _isFocused = isFocused
            _endEditing = endEditing
        }

        func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
            text = textField.text ?? ""
        }

        func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
               self.isFocused = true
            }
        }

        func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.isFocused = false
                self.endEditing = true
            }
        }

        func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Reusable textfield

```
struct CustomFieldUI: View {
    
    var title: String
    var placeHolderText: String
    var image: String
    
    
    @Binding var fieldString: String
    @Binding var isInValid: Bool
        @State private var isFocused = false
    
    @State var didEndEditing = false
    
            VStack(){
                HStack {
//                    TextField(fieldText, text: $fieldString, onEditingChanged: { edit in
//                                self.isActive = edit})
                    CustomTextFieldUI(text: $fieldString, isFocused: $isFocused, placeHolderText: placeHolderText, didEndEditing: $didEndEditing)
          
}
```

View that problem occurs in

```
struct AddPostalAddress: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var vm:AddNewPostalAddresViewModel = AddNewPostalAddresViewModel()
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode// use for the back button
    
    var body: some View {
      
                            CustomFieldUI(title: "Street Address Line 1", placeHolderText: "Type here", image: "ic_text field_check", fieldString: $vm.streetAddressLine1,isInValid: $vm.isInValidStreetAddressLine1, isErrorMessage: true, errorMsg: vm.streetAddressLine1ErrorMessage)
                                .padding(.top, 16)

    }}
```

view that i navigate from(if i remove the @Environment(.presentationMode) var presentationMode, from this view the problem goes away.

```
struct PostalAddressView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var vm = PostalAddressViewModel()
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @State private var showingDetail = false
    
    @State var defaultAddressID = 0
    //@Binding var hideView:Bool
    var body: some View {
                }
            }
            }
        .navigationBarTitle("test",displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .navigationBarItems(
            leading: Button(action: {
                //hideView = false
                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }, label: {
                Image("ic_calendar_back")
                    .renderingMode(.original)
            }),
            trailing:
                
                NavigationLink(
                                    destination: AddPostalAddress(),
                                    label: {
                                        Image("ic_nav_add")
                                        .renderingMode(.original)
                                    })
                .isDetailLink(false)
        )
}
```

Comment: Can you include the view setup that makes this situation happen in a [mre]?

Comment: can you check now?

Comment: That's not a [mre]. You've left out a ton of necessary types for it to compile (plus, just things that don't work -- look at your `body` code in `PostalAddressView` for example). Try to make an example that someone can copy and paste to try to make it work. Plus, that may help you debug the issue in the process.